# Creating a package under the folder other than src/ in ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I want to create a package `com.example.app.test` in the folder `test/java`.

When I create the package then it is created in the `src/com.example.app` folder.

How do I resolve this? I've tried created the package normally and drag and drop in `test/java`. But now it doesn't considers it package anymore.

Comment: `right click` on the project a then go to `new` and then a layout slides out then select `package`

Comment: You're right if we want to create new package. That's all right. But still doesn't answer my question. I want to create a package `com.example.android.test` in the `src/test/java` folder, but doing so creates the package in the default folder `src/`. Now i'm stuck with my project here

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
1. Right click /src -> New -> Source Folder -> Call it test
2. Right click /test-> New -> Source Folder -> Call it java
3. Right click /java-> New -> package -> com.whatever
```

And do not worry even if it shows up as a listing outside in project explorer.

Comment: You're creating two source folders. I found a better way. Create a folder in `src/test/java` and then Right click -> Build as source folder and yes. Solved.

Comment: I thought you did not have the the other folder at first. But glad that helps.